# Trying to run Sample App in Microsoft Cognitive-Face Python SDK gives Syntax Error:invalid syntax on @util.async

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-cognitive-services

I've been trying to run the Sample Application given on
https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Python .

I have downloaded all the required packages and modules.I've tried running the code on Git Bash and CMD and both give the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\aritrab507\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "C:\Users\aritrab507\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "sample\__main__.py", line 8, in <module>
from view import MyApp
File "sample\view\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
from view.panel_detection import DetectionPanel
File "sample\view\panel_detection.py", line 90
@util.async
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Some idea about where I could have gone wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: In newer Python versions `async` is a reserved keyword. Try running it in a Python version before 3.5.

Comment: I tried on a few different versions.The app runs fine on Python 2.7 (64 bit) as well from my  Anaconda Prompt which runs on Python 3.6.5 (64 bit) .
It only runs into errors on Python 3.7(which is a 32 bit version), which is weird.